# Granting permissions without user interactive screen

Tags: android, android-firmware

I am developing an Android application which is suppose to run on an embedded device which does not have UI. My application uses various permissions for which usually Android system will present user to grant permission. This is not possible in our case because the device does not have any screen. What is the way to grant permissions in this case. Note that, we can publish this app as System app as we can build our own firmware too but not sure about how to get past this user prompt.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already said you are going to publish this app as system application
you also need to mention this in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```